# Interpolation of formula in propositional logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Prove that there exists the such $\phi_n$ that $\phi_n$ contains only $p_1, .., p_n$ and $O(|\phi_n|) = n$.

$$\left((p_1\lor z_1)\land(\lnot z_1\lor p_2\lor z_2)\land(\lnot z_2\lor p_3\lor z_3)\land\ldots\land(\lnot z_{n-2}\lor p_{n-1}\lor z_{n-1})\land(\lnot z_{n-1}\lor p_n)\right)\to\varphi_n$$

$$\varphi_n\to\left[\left((p_1\to x_1)\land((x_1\lor p_2)\to x_2)\land((x_2\lor p_3)\to x_3)\land\ldots\land((x_{n-1}\lor p_{n})\to x_n)\right)\to x_n\right].$$

I guessed that it is $\bigvee_{i = 1..n} p_i$ but I cannot prove it in formal way. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hunch is correct.  Note that your interpolant is the result of existential quantification of the $z$ variables.  Therefore it is guaranteed to be implied by the formula from which you derived it.  (You can also directly observe that when all the $p_i$'s are false, the LHS formula is false.)

The other implication is also easy to verify because when at least one $p_i$ is true, it reduces to an implication of the form $(\psi \wedge x_n) \rightarrow x_n$.  Finally, the interpolant's size is clearly $O(n)$.

Comment: "(You can also directly observe that when all the pi's are false, the LHS formula is false.)" Yes, and I did it. But how to prove it in formal way ( by induction for instance)

Comment: In the end you invoke, more or less explicity, induction.  How explicitly you do so depends on the level of formality you want to achieve.  I'd start by observing that when all the $p_i$ are false, the formula simplifies to $z_1 \wedge (z_1 \rightarrow z_2) \wedge \cdots \wedge (z_{n-2} \rightarrow z_{n-1}) \wedge \neg z_{n-1}$.  Then you could resort to induction to prove that the conjunction of the first $n-1$ terms implies $z_{n-1}$.  Again, it depends on how detailed you need to be in your proof.